# cover page of my document

Tags: positioning

I would like to create a cover page.
I would like to put the name of my university, the name of my faculty and the name of my department in three lines between two logos. But I can not do it.
Someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `minipage` environment to put some elements next to each other on the same line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}\centering\bfseries\large
        Name of the university\\[1ex]
        Name of the faculty\\[1ex]
        Name of the department
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{minipage}

    \vfill

    \centering\huge\bfseries My Title\\[1em]
    \Large My Name

    \vfill
\end{titlepage}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]